# Create a payment schedule based on 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like the below.

| CONTRACT_ID | AMOUNT | FIRST_PAYMENT | LAST_PAYMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 5 JAN 2023 | 5 JAN 2024 |

I am trying to build a payment schedule that shows the monthly payment amount between the `FIRST_PAYMENT` and `LAST_PAYMENT`. The monthly amount will be the `ANOUNT` divided by the number of months between the first and last payment. It should look like the below. (just using 3 rows for example)

| CONTRACT_ID | AMOUNT | PAYMENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.38 | 5 JAN 2023 |
| 1 | 15.38 | 5 FEB 2023 |
| 1 | 15.38 | 5 MAR 2023 |

I am struggling to come up with the best way to achieve this.

Comment: I'd expect 13 payments here. One each month in 2023, and a final one in January 2024.

Comment: Yeah I have edited it.. was only showing 3 rows as an example

Comment: 200 / 13 = 15.38.

Comment: Could the last payment ever be on a day that isn't the same as the first? For example, the first is on the 5th, but the last on the 8th?

Comment: You need to join a calendar table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Contracts TABLE (Contract_id INT, Amount INT, First_Payment DATE, Last_Payment DATE)
INSERT INTO @Contracts (Contract_id, Amount, First_Payment, Last_Payment) VALUES
(1, 200,  '5 JAN 2023', '5 JAN 2024'),
(2, 1000, '5 JAN 2023', '5 JUN 2023');

;WITH payments AS (
SELECT Contract_id, First_Payment AS PaymentDate, Last_Payment
  FROM @Contracts
UNION ALL
SELECT Contract_id, DATEADD(MONTH,1,PaymentDate), Last_Payment
  FROM payments
 WHERE PaymentDate < Last_Payment
)

SELECT c.Contract_id, CAST(c.Amount AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / COUNT(p.PaymentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Contract_id ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Payment, p.PaymentDate
  FROM payments p
    INNER JOIN @Contracts c
      ON p.Contract_id = c.Contract_id
```

I took your example data, added a row, and converted it into example DDL/DML. As has already been pointed out in the comments, there are 13 payments, resulting in a equal payment of 15.38 over 13 months for the original example.

Here we're using a recursive CTE to generate a row per payment date for each contract. Then we can simply join back to the contract table. Using a windowed COUNT function we can get the total number of payments per contract and divide the original amount by them (after converting the int to a decimal).

| Contract_id | Payment | PaymentDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-02-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-03-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-04-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-05-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-06-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-07-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-08-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-10-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-11-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-12-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2024-01-05 |
| 1 | 15.3846153846153 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-02-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-03-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-04-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-05-05 |
| 2 | 166.6666666666666 | 2023-06-05 |

Edit:

To account for rounding that'd need to happen with currency here's an alternate version which figures out if there's an adjustment necessary for the final payment:

```
;WITH payments AS (
SELECT Contract_id, First_Payment AS PaymentDate, Last_Payment
  FROM @Contracts
UNION ALL
SELECT Contract_id, DATEADD(MONTH,1,PaymentDate), Last_Payment
  FROM payments
 WHERE PaymentDate < Last_Payment
)

SELECT a.Contract_id, CASE WHEN a.PaymentDate = a.Last_Payment THEN a.Payment + (Amount-SUM(Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY Contract_id ORDER BY a.PaymentDate)) ELSE Payment END AS Payment, a.PaymentDate,
SUM(a.Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Contract_id ORDER BY a.PaymentDate) AS RunningTotalPayment,
CASE WHEN a.PaymentDate = a.Last_Payment THEN (Amount-SUM(Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY Contract_id ORDER BY a.PaymentDate)) END AS FinalPaymentAdjustment
  FROM (
        SELECT c.Contract_id, CAST(CAST(c.Amount AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / COUNT(p.PaymentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Contract_id ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Payment, p.PaymentDate, c.Last_Payment, c.Amount
          FROM payments p
            INNER JOIN @Contracts c
              ON p.Contract_id = c.Contract_id
       ) a
```

Here we compare the running total, on the final payment only, to adjust the payment amount up or down to exactly meet the total payment amount.

| Contract_id | Payment | PaymentDate | RunningTotalPayment | FinalPaymentAdjustment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-01-05 | 15.38 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-02-05 | 30.76 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-03-05 | 46.14 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-04-05 | 61.52 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-05-05 | 76.90 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-06-05 | 92.28 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-07-05 | 107.66 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-08-05 | 123.04 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-09-05 | 138.42 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-10-05 | 153.80 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-11-05 | 169.18 |  |
| 1 | 15.38 | 2023-12-05 | 184.56 |  |
| 1 | 15.44 | 2024-01-05 | 199.94 | 0.06 |
| 2 | 166.67 | 2023-01-05 | 166.67 |  |
| 2 | 166.67 | 2023-02-05 | 333.34 |  |
| 2 | 166.67 | 2023-03-05 | 500.01 |  |
| 2 | 166.67 | 2023-04-05 | 666.68 |  |
| 2 | 166.67 | 2023-05-05 | 833.35 |  |
| 2 | 166.65 | 2023-06-05 | 1000.02 | -0.02 |

Comment: This certainly works. But using a recursive cte for this kind of thing can be a challenge from a performance perspective if you need to generate large amounts of numbers. For a small dataset like this it isn't an issue. Check out [this article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes) by Jeff Moden on the topic.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, however it's going to be directly relational to the number of contracts, and the number of payment dates involved at any given time. Even in the instance of a mortgage, over 30 years, we're only looking at 360 payments.

Comment: Yes I know that in this instance the performance is not an issue. But it should be pointed out in case others come across this and use it on a large dataset where the performance would be dreadful. A tally table would eliminate the performance risk. But regardless it already has a +1 from me. ;)

Comment: Just don't forget, @PatrickHurst , that you can't have someone pay you less than a penny. If you round these values to 2 decimal places, you end up losing money. A penny here and there is nothing, but when you have millions or billions of them they are a very significant amount of money.

Comment: If we wanna go whole hog we'll need to factor in compound interest and other such fun factors as well. The intent isn't to solve the whole problem. It wouldn't be too hard to include some logic that uses a windowed function to determine the amount paid and make an adjustment to the final payment to factor in actual money paid, but that's beyond the scope, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier with some kind of Tally function. Unfortunately, as you're on SQL Server 2016, you don't have access to `GENERATE_SERIES` so I use a "helper" function called `Tally`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@LastNumber bigint, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
          AND @LastNumber IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@LastNumber,0))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
```

One thing to note, however, is that when working with (what are presumably) monetary values you can't just go ahead and divide these into equal parts. Take your example of 200 in 13 payments, `200 / 13 = 15.38461538461538` but you can't ask someone to pay you 0.461~ pence/cents/etc per payment. As such what you'll need to do is ensure that any "lost" pennies are added to one of the payments. I add them to the *first* payment.

This results in a little more a complicated problem. First you split the value into 13 payments, based on the number of months+1 difference in the payment dates. Then in the bottom part of the query I check that the `SUM` of the values is equal to that of the expected total; if it isn't I add the remainder to the first payment. This result in the first payment for the example being 15.44, and all subsequent payments being 15.38:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,200.,CONVERT(date,'20230105'),CONVERT(date,'20240105')),
            (2,120.,CONVERT(date,'20230105'),CONVERT(date,'20241205')))V(ContractID, Amount, FirstPayment, LastPayment);
GO
WITH Amounts AS(
    SELECT YT.ContractID,
           CONVERT(decimal(16,2),YT.Amount / COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID)) AS Amount,
           YT.Amount AS TotalAmount,
           DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, FirstPayment) AS PaymentDate,
           T.I
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
        CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(DATEDIFF(MONTH,FirstPayment,LastPayment),0) T)
SELECT ContractID,
       --Amount,
       CASE TotalAmount WHEN SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID) THEN Amount
            ELSE CASE I WHEN 0 THEN TotalAmount - SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractID ORDER BY I
                                                                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
                        ELSE Amount
                 END
       END AS Amount,
       PaymentDate
FROM Amounts A
ORDER BY ContractID,
         PaymentDate;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```